understanding the concept of "least squares" in linear algebra
I'm studying orthogonality in linear algebra, but am struggling to grasp the "least" part of least squares.  I get that when you have a vector $b$ that falls outside $C(A)$, there is no solution vector $x$ such that $Ax=b$.  However, $b$ will lie somewhere in $\Bbb{R^m}$ and its location must be in $N(A^T)$ since $C(A)$ and $N(A^T)$ are orthogonal complements and together, they span all of $\Bbb{R^m}$
It makes intuitive sense that the least distance from $b$ to $C(A)$ will be a vector $e$ that is perpendicular to $C(A)$ and meets $C(A)$ at the point $A\hat{x}$, forming a right triangle with hypotenuse $b$, such that $\Vert{b}\Vert^2=\Vert{e}\Vert^2+\Vert{A\hat{x}}\Vert^2$
So, I assume this last equation is where the idea of least squares come from, but I don't see any other option for "squares" that would produce a larger $e$.  If I choose any other vector $x$, except for $\hat{x}$, $e$ will no longer be perpendicular to $C(A)$ making $\Vert{b}\Vert^2=\Vert{e}\Vert^2+\Vert{Ax}\Vert^2$ untrue. If $Ax$ is shorter, $e$ will be shorter, but $b$ would be different.
It seems, in this context, that a better descriptive term would be the "only square" rather than "least squares". What am I missing here?

No, $b$ does not necessarily lie in $N(A^\top)$. If it does, $0$ is the least squares solution.

Is it also incorrect to say that $C(A)$ and $N(A^T)$, taken together, span all of $\Bbb{R^m}$ ?

No, that’s perfectly fine. A subspace and its orthogonal complement always span the whole space.

I'm confused about the first comment still.  If the least squares solution is $0$ ($e=0$), doesn't that mean $b$ is in $C(A)$?

No, the solution is not $e$. The error is $e$ and that will be all of $b$.

No, the equation $\|b\|^2 = \|e\|^2 + \|A\hat x\|^2$ is not the origin of the terminology. Actually, the "least squares" method is, when written out more completely, the least squared errors method.
When we think of $\hat x$ as an approximate solution to $Ax = b$, the "errors" involved are the differences $A\hat x - b$. The sum of the squares of the errors is $\|A \hat x - b\|^2$. Therefore the approximate solution with the least squared errors will be the vector $\hat x$ that minimizes $\|A \hat x - b\|^2$.
The sum of squares in $\|A \hat x - b\|^2$ is the squares that are "least" in the solution we want.
Then we can re-interpret this vector as "the vector $\hat x$ such that $A\hat x$ is the closest element of $C(A)$ to $b$", and deduce the constraint you're treating as fundamental: that $A \hat x -b$ should be orthogonal to $C(A)$.
